# CSV writer will not write first line in file (code contains: dictwriter,numbering lines, values equal to other csv, length of element, etc.)

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, dictionary

My code almost works and it is driving me crazy. I have code that takes a csv file, numbers the lines, finds the number of characters of all the fields in a column, writes all of these to a new csv and copies all of the other lines from the original csv file into the new csv. (I hope that makes sense).

My code:

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter


with open('file1') as fil1,\ # Original file
     open('file2') as fil2,\ # File 2 (for line num and length headers)
     open('file3', 'wb') as fcompout,

# file3 is new file (to be original file +: line numbers and length of 'Name')

    read1 = DictReader(fil1)
    read2 = DictReader(fil2)

    writenum = DictWriter(fcompout, fieldnames=read2.fieldnames)
    writenum.writeheader()


    num = 0 # Number value
    for line1 in read1:
        newdic=dict(line1)
        fil2.seek(0) # resets the reader1 iterator
        for line2 in read2:
            num=num+1 # Number for line num
            outline1=dict(line2)
            outline1['Name']=newdic['Name']
            outline1['Length']=len(newdic['Name']) # Length of Name
            outline1['Line Num']=num # Line Numbers
            outline1['Geo Location']=newdic['Geo Location']
            outline1['IPStart']=newdic['IPStart']
            outline1['IPStop']=newdic['IPStop']
            outline1['Command']=newdic['Command']
            outline1['file']=newdic['file']
            outline1['NA']=newdic['NA']
            outline1['Default']=newdic['Default']
            writenum.writerow(outline1) # Write line to new csv
```

Original file (file1):

```
Command,Name,file,Geo Location,NA,Default,IPStart,IPStop
,DRE EXT Ascent Media,,,,,,
,DRE United Kingdom UKLONEXT LON Extrane lo0.UKLONEXT sw01,,United Kingdom,,,,
,DRE United Kingdom UKLONEXT LON Extrane lo0.UKLONEXT sw02,,United Kingdom,,,,
,DRE United Kingdom UKLONDRE LON Sq lab dynamips test nets,,United Kingdom,,,,
,DRE United States USLAXCPT Corp Point Multilink_Ascent Media,,United States,,,,
,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE01 to SW01,,United Kingdom,,,,
,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE01 to SW02,,United Kingdom,,,,
,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE02 to SW01,,United Kingdom,,,,
,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE02 to SW02,,United Kingdom,,,,
,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE01 to CORE02,,United Kingdom,,,,
,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D SW01 to SW02,,United Kingdom,,,,
,DRE United States USLAXMDR SASD-D XC VRF T1/7 Xconnect to vrf via Te1/7,,United States,,,,
,DRE Hong Kong (China) HKHKGEXT Hongkong Extranet HKHKGDRE SW01 interconnect,,"Hong Kong, Hong Kong",,,,
,DRE United Kingdom UKLONDRE LON Sq lab test nets,,United Kingdom,,,,
,DRE United States USLAXTHA SPS Thalberg uslaxtha mdf01 Interconnect,,United States,,,,
,DRE Hong Kong (China) HKHKGDRE SASD-D Citiplaza to EXT Interconnect,,Hong Kong,,,,
,SASD-D United States USPHXCAP VRF SW02,,United States,,,,
```

For headers/new columns (file2):

```
Line Num,Command,Name,Length,file,Geo Location,NA,Default,IPStart,IPStop
```

New file (file3):

```
Line Num,Command,Name,Length,file,Geo Location,NA,Default,IPStart,IPStop
1,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONEXT LON Extrane lo0.UKLONEXT sw01,57,,United Kingdom,,,,
2,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONEXT LON Extrane lo0.UKLONEXT sw02,57,,United Kingdom,,,,
3,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONDRE LON Sq lab dynamips test nets,57,,United Kingdom,,,,
4,,DRE United States USLAXCPT Corp Point Multilink_Ascent Media,60,,United States,,,,
5,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE01 to SW01,49,,United Kingdom,,,,
6,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE01 to SW02,49,,United Kingdom,,,,
7,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE02 to SW01,49,,United Kingdom,,,,
8,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE02 to SW02,49,,United Kingdom,,,,
9,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE01 to CORE02,51,,United Kingdom,,,,
10,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D SW01 to SW02,47,,United Kingdom,,,,
11,,DRE United States USLAXMDR SASD-D XC VRF T1/7 Xconnect to vrf via Te1/7,71,,United States,,,,
12,,DRE Hong Kong (China) HKHKGEXT Hongkong Extranet HKHKGDRE SW01 interconnect,75,,"Hong Kong, Hong Kong",,,,
13,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONDRE LON Sq lab test nets,48,,United Kingdom,,,,
14,,DRE United States USLAXTHA SPS Thalberg uslaxtha mdf01 Interconnect,67,,United States,,,,
15,,DRE Hong Kong (China) HKHKGDRE SASD-D Citiplaza to EXT Interconnect,67,,Hong Kong,,,,
16,,SASD-D United States USPHXCAP VRF SW02,38,,United States,,,,
```

file3 above is the current output from my code. Notice how it is missing the first line from file1 . It doesn't matter if I change the order to make another line first, it is always missing the first one and all the other lines look perfect. I can't figure it out.

Please help...

Thanks,
B0T

Comment: I've been reading your code for five minutes now and I'm not getting what you're doing there. Why are you reading the same line in `fil2` over and over again? Also, why the `dict()` calls? You already have a `dict`. You also don't need to construct a dict only to overwrite all its fields again. `outline1 = {}` should be enough, shouldn't it?

Comment: Also, that `with` statement is incomplete. What did you remove?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I removed some with statements for other files that aren't in the code at all yet. There is another step for me to work on once this is working.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Okay, I will try it without the second dictionary. I'm still new at this and it's hard for me to figure out when it's necessary to make a new dictionary and when not. I usually go off of what has worked before, but it's not always the same thing exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite know what you're doing there, but it's much easier:

```
from csv import DictReader, DictWriter

with open('file1') as fil1, open('file2') as fil2, open('file3', 'wb') as fcompout:
    read1 = DictReader(fil1)
    read2 = DictReader(fil2)
    writenum = DictWriter(fcompout, fieldnames=read2.fieldnames)
    writenum.writeheader()

    for num, line in enumerate(read1):
        line['Length'] = len(line['Name']) # Length of Name
        line['Line Num'] = num+1           # Line Numbers
        writenum.writerow(line)            # Write line to new csv
```

You don't need to reassign all those values - just add the ones you need additionally.

Result:

```
Line Num,Command,Name,Length,file,Geo Location,NA,Default,IPStart,IPStop
1,,DRE EXT Ascent Media,20,,,,,,
2,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONEXT LON Extrane lo0.UKLONEXT sw01,57,,United Kingdom,,,,
3,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONEXT LON Extrane lo0.UKLONEXT sw02,57,,United Kingdom,,,,
4,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONDRE LON Sq lab dynamips test nets,57,,United Kingdom,,,,
5,,DRE United States USLAXCPT Corp Point Multilink_Ascent Media,60,,United States,,,,
6,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE01 to SW01,49,,United Kingdom,,,,
7,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE01 to SW02,49,,United Kingdom,,,,
8,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE02 to SW01,49,,United Kingdom,,,,
9,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE02 to SW02,49,,United Kingdom,,,,
10,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D CORE01 to CORE02,51,,United Kingdom,,,,
11,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONSDD SASD-D SW01 to SW02,47,,United Kingdom,,,,
12,,DRE United States USLAXMDR SASD-D XC VRF T1/7 Xconnect to vrf via Te1/7,71,,United States,,,,
13,,DRE Hong Kong (China) HKHKGEXT Hongkong Extranet HKHKGDRE SW01 interconnect,75,,"Hong Kong, Hong Kong",,,,
14,,DRE United Kingdom UKLONDRE LON Sq lab test nets,48,,United Kingdom,,,,
15,,DRE United States USLAXTHA SPS Thalberg uslaxtha mdf01 Interconnect,67,,United States,,,,
16,,DRE Hong Kong (China) HKHKGDRE SASD-D Citiplaza to EXT Interconnect,67,,Hong Kong,,,,
17,,SASD-D United States USPHXCAP VRF SW02,38,,United States,,,,
```